# !is.na Remove columns with NA value (in any rows)

Tags: r

I have a 17(r) by 20 (c) matrix where all data is numbers and NA.  I am trying to remove all columns that has the value NA in any rows. This is 11 of the 20 columns. I've been searching for an hour and tried several methods but couldn't get it right.

```
my.data [ ,!is.na(my.data[ ,1:20])]
```

To me this makes the most sense but is giving 'script too long' error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One basic approach would be

```
mydata[, !is.na(colSums(mydata))]
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I was going to suggest ```mydata[ , colSums(is.na(mydata)) == 0]```

Comment: Thank you very much. So the logic is - sum values in a column and because any NA value will turn the sum to NA...the !is.na will filter them out.

Comment: @RandyMarsh correct!

Comment: Having said that.. is my initial approach not suitable for what I was trying to do or is there an obvious error I'm not seeing? thanks again Ric S

Comment: It gives you that error because `is.na` takes, according to the documentation, "atomic vectors, lists, pairlists, and NULL", thus no matrices or dataframes